# Compare MySQL Date with c#/Nhibernate Date

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

How can i compare a Mysql Date (without time) with the current date in Nhibernate

```
data = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(DataModel))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("date", DateTime.Now))
                    .UniqueResult<DataModel>();
```

this wont work because DateTime now holds the time or why do i get data = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTime.Now.Date instead of DateTime.Now:

```
data = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(DataModel))
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("date", DateTime.Now.Date))
             .UniqueResult<DataModel>();
```